# jquery slideup doesn't seem to be sliding smoothly

Tags: jquery, slideup

When I call slideup or slidedown on my div, it seems to be sliding very very fast.  Do I need to slideup all the inner elements also?

my DOM:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="inside">hi</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should not need to but you can specify slideUp("slow"). Have you tried that yet?

Comment: you can also specify milliseconds

Comment: I tried slow, I tried 300, still going really fast.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page that shows the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the speed?

http://jsbin.com/odiji/edit

Explore the example above where I set the speed to be 5000 which will slide the element over 5 seconds.